# Java can't find symbols, error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get the name and the value of the variable but it's giving my a "Can't Find Symbol" error. Is there something wrong with my variables?

Main http://pastebin.com/Us1f07xN

Class http://pastebin.com/qHnWrk20

Comment: Can you provide the full error you are getting from the compiler?

Comment: --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
K:\CDApp.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(cdList.displayCDInfoInOneLine());
                                 ^
  symbol:   method displayCDInfoInOneLine()
  location: variable cdList of type CD[]
1 error

Process completed.

Comment: And post your relevant code here, not in links.

Comment: You can't call that method on the array as a whole. Do you mean to call that method on a single element in the array?

Answer (score 1):

I see, you're trying to make a list of `CD` objects print nicely. As Kon stated, you're attempting to invoke the method `displayCDInfoInOneLine()` on an array of `CD` objects, when arrays don't understand that method.

Here is how you can achieve your intention. First, add a `toString()` method in your `CD` class, like this:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return displayCDInfoInOneLine();
    }
```

Then, change the `displayCDInfo()` method in your `CDApp` class like this:

```
    public static void displayCDInfo() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(cdList));
    }
```

The other option is to print each CD on a separate line, like this:

```
    public static void displayCDInfo() {
        for (CD cd: cdList) {
            System.out.println(cd); // assuming CD.toString() as above
        }
    }
```